# How can I display the result of a bitwise operation in binary form?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting decimal to binary in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203974/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-java)

I have found this code that takes as an input a number `x`, an array `p` and another number `pmax` which indicates the size of the array `p`

```
public static int permute(int x, int p[], int pmax) {
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; ++i) {
        y <<= 1;
        y |= (x >> (pmax - p[i])) & 1;
    }

    return y;
}
```

this code should be permutating the bits of the first byte that is stored in the number `x`
according to the rules defined in the array `p`

so for example if the first pmax bits of `x` are `101` and the array p is the following:
`p={2 1 3}`
then the result of this function(`y`) will be equal to `011`

**Question**

I have never worked with bitwise operators and I would like to see all the intermediate results of the above code. For example what does `y<<=1` do and why it is used. To do this I need to somewhat display the `y` variable in the binary form, otherwise I just get some random decimals which doesn't help me understand anything.

So how can I display after each bitwise operation the result in binary format?

If this is not a good method to learn exactly what this code does, what method would you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Integer.toBinaryString(int x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) will do this for you.

Comment: I'd rather close this question as an easy duplicate than award the fastest gun in the west and his deputies 10 XP each.

Comment: @JanDvorak The linked duplicate is related to writing a handmade method that converts the number to generate the binary string. I even voted this question to be closed but this doesn't imply I can't spend 10 seconds of my time answering in the meanwhile. If it's going to be closed then it will happen anyway.

Answer (score 3):

are you looking for [`Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) ?