# How to convert Decimal to Binary Numbers in Java using JFrame?

Tags: java, binary, decimal, jcreator

I've been searching for all codes in the internet, but all I see is for Buffered Reader. Is it possible to have it in a JFrame format? I am new to Java and I wanted to create this program which will convert a decimal number to binary and vice versa. Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got a Frame? Input/Outputs? [this previous question might be of some help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203974/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-java)

Comment: Ye I have tried something like that but what I wanted to do is to use a GUI. I mean is it still the same process? And I was adding up some JOptionPane too.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'convert decimal to binary numbers in Java using JFrame'. Your question makes zero sense.

Comment: JFrame is the GUI and what I want is to create a conversion program with a GUI. If you misunderstood my question well I am sorry. But this question is already answered. Others don't mind how the question is imposed, as long as they can answered the question properly, it STILL make sense.

Comment: There is nothing to understand. A contradiction in terms cannot be understood. You need to clarify your question, not shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Converting* and *rendering* (displaying) are completely unrelated issues.

To convert, use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29):

```
String input = "10"; // some number as your input
int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

To display, put that String into the display area (too trivial to bother with here)

Comment: Can i put "String input;" rather than placing a specific number? What I want is that, when a user enter a number in a JTextField, it will convert to a binary and vice versa. I tried copying what I see in some sites using BufferedReader but I keep getting errors

Comment: My code is just an example that compiles. You would get your input from the text field, something like `String input = textField.getText();`