# Binary String Representation to File and the to String again

Tags: java, string, binary, huffman-code

I need to put binary in a file and then getting it back again, but i need to make it with the less amount possible of space use in the file ( example 16 bits = 2 bytes)

```
byte[] b = new BigInteger("1011010101010110", 2).toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file",true);
fos.write(b);
```

I used this to write the "1011010101010110" to a file in binary representation (2 bytes of space)

But now i am not getting how can i read it from the file again and turn it back to a string of  "1011010101010110" again.

When I open the file with the binary with Notepadd++ , it have weird characters ( i dont know if its normal).

Comment: text editors cant interpret binary files. That is why you see "weird" characters. You need to read the two bytes from the file and unpack them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert the [Binary to Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal) (which occupy less space, because they have less characters, Eg; Binary 1001 == Decimal  9), and then write to files (as `String`).

While reading back, you can convert the [decimals to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203974/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-java) again

Comment: I need to do it in the other way, cause im using the Huffman algoritm and the binary sequence is going to be big and must be writen to the file in binary.

Comment: the propose of writing 1001 in binary is that is takes only 4 bits, the decimal 9 in String will take 8 bits.